# Selecting a Child in xPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Looking at w3schools for xPath (feel free to give me other references), you can select all the children of `bookstore`, but what if I wanted to only select the second book element? How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Comment: As for other XPath references: this may sound stupid or "overkill" but read the [w3c XPath recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). Usually specs are long, complicated etc. XPath specification is somewhat short, has nice examples and simply contains all the info on axes, functions etc. in the same place. Some might say I'm weird but I'd say it is actually quite readable stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could select the n-th element with `[n]`, e.g.

```
/bookstore/book[2]
```

See "Predicates" in http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp for detail.

Comment: Positions are rarely a good choice in XML.  Better is some other detail that allows you to select the node you care about.

Comment: Off topic: I think you should open a discussion on Meta about your `xsltprocessor` to `xslt` tag synonym proposal. Or at least check chat discussion at http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165/xslt-and-xpath